# Sharing source files between projects

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, mfc

I have project `A` that contains source files with class definition and implementation `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.cpp`. `MyClass` is using `CString`.

Now I decided to make new project `B` that is simple console application for testing `MyClass` purpose. In solution explorer I added `MyClass` header and cpp file to my project from `A` project location. Till this moment I didn't knew that I must use `MFC` to use `CString`. I tried to build project and got error that as far I understood asks to use MFC.

```
#error :  Building MFC application with /MD[d] (CRT dll version) requires MFC shared dll version. Please #define _AFXDLL or do not use /MD[d]
```

To understand what is going on I decide to remove MyClass and create simple `MyCLass2` in project `B` that is also using `CString`. After building `B` I got errors like

```
Error   22  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'CString'
```

Includes in `MyClass` and `MyClass2` are identical.

Why in MyClass case I was asked to add `MFC` lib? I suppose in this case compiler knows what is `CString`. How does it knows?

I was expecting to get the same result like compiling with `MyClass2` when system does not understand what is `CString`.

Comment: You probably want to make a [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) and you may want to make a shared library. Details are operating system and compiler specific.

Comment: project A is MFC windows application. Project B is console application. Both of them are not shared libs.

Comment: But you could make a library of the common source code.

Comment: yes, this might be solution. But I would like use shared code style to prevent misunderstanding with different lib versions later. Anyway my question is not how to solve problem, but how to understand this strange VS behavior.

Comment: Do you have both your projects in the same folder? In the first case, it might be that the existing object file for MyClass was reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyClass` and `MyClass2` both include `stdafx.h` which is different in two projects.
What you can do is to rename/delete `stdafx.h` which belongs to project A and see where you get compile error.

Comment: I expect since MyClass is in B project it must use stdafx.h of B project like MyClass2

Comment: Check that it has the option "Precompiled Header/Use" then.

Comment: I suppose you've checked if there are other local files that can be included and have different contents? Also note that if `#include "stdafx.h"` is not the first statement in cpp file, also local file will be included. It can happen if for example it's included by some .h files included by MyClass.cpp

Comment: The ultimate check is to put `#error "Wrong stdafx.h included"` in stdafx.h from project A.

Comment: Nice try! I got "Wrong stdafx.h included". Then why project B includes projects A stdafx? Where is logic?

Comment: Check carefully includes of `MyClass.cpp`. Maybe removal one by one will help. Also you can put `#error test` between includes in MyClass.cpp to see if it happens before or after "Wrong stdafx.h included" so by binary search you can find the source of error. And remove downvote from my answer, if it was you :)

Answer (score 3):

> If using in an ATL application:
>
> CString, CStringA, and CStringW are exported from the MFC DLL
>   (MFC90.DLL), never from user DLLs. This is done to prevent CStringT
>   from being multiply defined.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx

If you want to use without linking to MFC then you can use following classes: CAtlString, CAtlStringA, and CAtlStringW.